# Gitosis: setting repository config variables

Tags: git, variables, gitolite, gitosis

Is there a way to set repository config variables through the gitosis conf instead of going into each repository and editing the conf values directly?

Comment: For others (like me) who hadn't heard of it, the Gitosis site is http://eagain.net/gitweb/?p=gitosis.git , here's an article about it: http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible.
On the other hand, it's quite simple to build "porcelain" script that analyzes your gitosis.conf for some special comments encoding the conf values.
Then putting such script in a post-commit hook should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Note (10 years later, 2018), gitosis has long been replaced by **[gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/)**.

And gitolite offers a way to [specify config variables through gitolite configuration](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/git-config/).

> The syntax is simple:
>
> ```
> config sectionname.keyname = value
> ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> repo gitolite
>     config hooks.mailinglist = gitolite-commits@example.tld
>     config hooks.emailprefix = "[gitolite] "
>     config foo.bar = ""
> ```
>
> This does either a plain "`git config section.key value`" (for the first 2 examples above) or "`git config --unset-all section.key`" (for the last example).
>   Other forms of the `git config` command (`--add`, the value_regex, etc) are not supported.